# OctoberCMS component causes a memory error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, octobercms

I made a component in OctoberCMS and it causes a memory error.
The component has just a quite simple function.
I don't know why it causes such an error.

I've edited the memory_limit up to 1024M in php.ini but nothing changed.

**Component file**

```php
<?php
namespace Jiwon\Byapps\Components;

use Cms\Classes\Page;
use Cms\Classes\ComponentBase;
use Exception;
use Jiwon\Byapps\Models\Comment;

class Comments extends ComponentBase
{
  public $comments;

  public function componentDetails()
  {
      return [
          'name'        => 'Comment List',
          'description' => 'comment list'
      ];
  }

  public function defineProperties()
  {
      return [
          'display' => [
              'title'       => 'number of the comments',
              'description' => 'number of the comments list',
              'default'     => 10,
              'validationPattern' => '^[0-9]+$',
              'validationMessage' => 'only number'
          ],
      ];
  }

  public function onRun()
  {
     $this->comments = $this->loadComments();
  }

  protected function loadComments() {

     $query = Comment::all();

     if ($this->property('display') > 0) {
       $query = $query->take($this->property('display'));

     }

     return $query;
  }
}
?>
```

I put this component in the aside of partials and this error shows in every page.

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8192 bytes)
>   /home/ljw/public_html/byapps_cms/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php line 290

**Comment model file**

```php
<?php namespace Jiwon\Byapps\Models;

use Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\Validation;

    public $timestamps = false;

    public $connection = 'byapps';
    public $table = 'BYAPPS_comment_data';
}
```

Comment: the `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted` usually means that you got somewhere infinite loop. take a look at your code or post more data like your model Comment to see what cause that.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco I added the comment model. It's just a simple model. I can't even think anything that causes an infinite loop.

Comment: Try with `memory_limit = 1` in `php.ini` and don't forget to restart the server.

Comment: @Jiwon Are you working in local system?

Comment: @DhananjayKyada memory_limit = 1? What does that do?

Comment: @Jiwon It will set `memory_limit` to `infinite`. So that application won't through memory limit error.

Comment: @BhavinThummar Not in the local system, I'm doing this in the working server.

Comment: @Jiwon, If you were worked in a local system,  after any change in the php.ini file, we need to restart our server so that change will be the effect on server

Comment: @DhananjayKyada  In case of that, isn't it '-1'? And... should I do that? I'm not sure of that.

Comment: @BhavinThummar  Yeap, I restart the server every time I edited the php.ini file.

Comment: @Jiwon. Sorry, it's type mistake it should be `-1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with a query, you are trying to use. Try this instead of your query.

```
public function loadComments() {

 $query = Comment::query();

 if (!empty($this->property('display'))) {
   $query = $query->limit($this->property('display'));

 }

 $query = $query->get();
 return $query;
}
```

And yes, as your are trying to get limited items from the table, Don't forget to set OrderBy(), so that you can get your desired result.

Comment: It solved!! Thank you!! You're a lifesaver. Thank you.

Comment: @Jiwon Welcome. **all()** get all results from the database, when you use **get()** function, your query like **limit(), where()** can be applied, so use get() when you need to apply query in future.

Thank you. If you will give upvote too, it would be great. :P

Comment: I upvote to your answer. But somehow it doesn't show up. !_!